# How to overlap the user star ratings ? Half star & full star into one star

Tags: html, css

How to overlap the user star ratings? Half star & full star into one star. I am having issues in rating section.

Please see my code in the attached link.

https://codepen.io/Abanerhee/pen/XWmeOPp?editors=1100

```css
:root {
  --color-white: #f3f3f3;
  --color-darkblue: #1b1b32;
  --color-darkblue-alpha: rgba(27, 27, 50, 0.8);
  --color-green: #37af65;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1 rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--color-white);
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: var(--color-darkblue);
  background-image: linear-gradient(115deg, rgba(58, 58, 158, 0.5), rgba(136, 136, 206, 0.5)), url(https://i.postimg.cc/B6W8JdzD/stars.png);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.12rem;
}

h1,
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

button {
  border: none;
}

.head {
  padding: 0 0.625rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.explaination {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.desc {
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}


/* form */

form {
  background: var(--color-darkblue-alpha);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 2.5rem 0.625rem;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  form {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
}

.form-name {
  margin: 0 auto 1.25rem auto;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.375rem;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.input-radio,
.input-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
  min-height: 1.25rem;
  min-width: 1.25rem;
}

.input-textarea {
  min-height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  resize: vertical;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: var(--color-green);
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* RATING SECTION */

fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}


/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half::before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}


/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating>input:checked~label,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  /* show gold star when clicked */
  /* hover current star */
  color: #ffd700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  /* hover current star when changing rating */
  /* lighten current selection */
  color: #ffed85;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-name">
  <p> Ratings !!!</p>
  <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the CSS to make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

add below CSS.

```css
.rating > label:nth-child(even) {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```css
:root {
  --color-white: #f3f3f3;
  --color-darkblue: #1b1b32;
  --color-darkblue-alpha: rgba(27, 27, 50, 0.8);
  --color-green: #37af65;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body::before {
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1 rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0;
  color: var(--color-white);
  line-height: 1.4;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: var(--color-darkblue);
  background-image: linear-gradient(115deg, rgba(58, 58, 158, 0.5), rgba(136, 136, 206, 0.5)), url(https://i.postimg.cc/B6W8JdzD/stars.png);
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 3.125rem auto 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

p {
  font-size: 1.12rem;
}

h1,
p {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  color: white;
}

input,
button,
select,
textarea {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
}

button {
  border: none;
}

.head {
  padding: 0 0.625rem;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.explaination {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-style: italic;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  text-align: center;
}

.heading {
  text-align: center;
}

.desc {
  margin-bottom: 1.45rem;
}


/* form */

form {
  background: var(--color-darkblue-alpha);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  padding: 2.5rem 0.625rem;
}

@media (min-width: 480px) {
  form {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
}

.form-name {
  margin: 0 auto 1.25rem auto;
  padding: 0.25rem;
}

.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.375rem;
  padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
  color: #495057;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  transition: border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
}

.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #80bdff;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.2rem rgba(0, 123, 255, 0.25);
}

.input-radio,
.input-checkbox {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 0.625rem;
  min-height: 1.25rem;
  min-width: 1.25rem;
}

.input-textarea {
  min-height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.625rem;
  resize: vertical;
}

.submit-button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.75rem;
  background: var(--color-green);
  color: inherit;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* RATING SECTION */

fieldset,
label {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin: 10px;
}


/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating {
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating>input {
  display: none;
}

.rating>label:before {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating>.half::before {
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating>label {
  color: #ddd;
  float: right;
}


/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating>input:checked~label,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
  /* show gold star when clicked */
  /* hover current star */
  color: #ffd700;
}


/* hover previous stars in list */

.rating>input:checked+label:hover,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover,
.rating>label:hover~input:checked~label,
.rating>input:checked~label:hover~label {
  /* hover current star when changing rating */
  /* lighten current selection */
  color: #ffed85;
}

.rating > label:nth-child(even) {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="form-name">
  <p> Ratings !!!</p>
  <fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
    <label for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4half" name="rating" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4half" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3half" name="rating" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3half" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2half" name="rating" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2half" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1half" name="rating" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1half" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalf" name="rating" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalf" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes . Thak you . It solved my issue. Could you also explain the logic why you added this ?

Comment: yes, the key is `position: absolute`. so you start rendering two different elements from the same origin point. Please give an upvote and accept the answer.